# Sufficient conditions for contraction mapping for unbounded functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose we have a family  $B(\mathbb R^n)$ of real valued functions e.g. $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

If $\mathcal{T}$ is a contraction mapping on $B(\mathbb R^n)$ then there exists a constant $\alpha \in (0,1)$ such that
$$
| \mathcal{T} f'(x) - \mathcal{T} f''(x)| \leq \alpha | f'(x) - f''(x) |
$$ 
for all $f',f''\in B(\mathbb R^n)$ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Are there any sufficient conditions such that $\mathcal{T}$ is a contraction on $B(\mathbb R^n)$ when $B(\mathbb R^n)$ contains unbounded functions?

I've learnt in class about Blackwell's sufficient conditions. However, these conditions require $B(\mathbb R^n)$ to be a family of bounded functions.

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087885/blackwells-condition-for-a-contraction-why-is-boundedness-neccessary

Comment: @uniquesolution : I don't think $B(R^n)$ needs to be bounded functions. Let $n=1$ and $B(R)$ be a family of linear functons. Here, $B(R)$ is a family of unbounded functions. Define $\mathcal{T} f = f / 2$.  Now $\mathcal{T}$ is a contraction mapping on $B(R)$ because $| \mathcal{T}f'(x) - \mathcal{T}f''(x)| \leq 0.5 |f'(x) - f''(x)|$ for all $x\in R$.